# Why does compiler say it can't see a template it has just generated?

Tags: c++, templates, operator-keyword

If you look at the following (edited) compiler output (Visual C++ 2013) you will see that on line 5 it tells me it is compiling (I use an explicit instantiation in a precompiled header):

```
TimeOnly IT_TimeOnly::operator ++<TimeOnly>(int).
```

This is the templated postfix operator for `IT_TimeOnly` class.
However, on line 7 the compiler warns that a postfix operator for type `IT_TimeOnly` cannot be found. Can anyone help me understand why?
My code is shown below.

```
1>------ Build started: Project: TemplatedPostFix, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
2>  stdafx.cpp
3>  Precompiled Header
4>c:...\it_timeonly.h(14): warning C4305: 'initializing' : truncation from 'int' to 'bool'
5> c:... \to_timeonly.h(22) : see reference to function template instantiation 'TimeOnly IT_TimeOnly::operator ++<TimeOnly>(int)' being compiled
6> Test_TemplatedPostFix.cpp
7>c:...\test_templatedpostfix.cpp(31): warning C4620: no postfix form of 'operator ++' found for type 'IT_TimeOnly', using prefix form
```

My Interface class with templated postfix:

```
typedef signed char period_t;

class IT_TimeOnly
{
public:
    template<class T>
    T operator++(int) {
        bool b = 2;  // here to generate warning for debugging
        std::cout << "Template Post++\n"; 
        return static_cast<T*>(this)->operator++(1); 
    }
    virtual IT_TimeOnly & operator++() = 0;
    virtual period_t getMins() const = 0;
    virtual void setMins(period_t) = 0;
};
```

My concrete derived class:

```
class TimeOnly : public IT_TimeOnly
{
public:
    TimeOnly(){};
    TimeOnly(const IT_TimeOnly &);
    TimeOnly(const TimeOnly &);
    TimeOnly operator++(int);
    TimeOnly & operator++() override  {
        cout << "Derived Pre++\n";
        ++mins;
        return *this;
    }
    period_t getMins() const override;
    void setMins(period_t mins) override;
private:
    period_t hrs = 0;
    period_t mins = 0;
};
```

I have explicitly instantiated the template for TimeOnly in my pre-compiled header. That produces lines 3, 4 and 5.

```
template TimeOnly IT_TimeOnly::operator++<TimeOnly>(int);
```

And my test code:

```
IT_TimeOnly & myBaseTime = myTime; // Base-class reference
myBaseTime++;
cout << (int)myBaseTime.getMins() << '\n';

// Prints: 
// Derived Pre++
// 1
```

Comment: `template` `operator ++` ?

Comment: It's not possible to do it the way you want to do it. How would the base-class `operator++` function know what the child-class is unless you specifically specify the template. To solve this you might have to use the [Curiously recurring template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think your answer addresses the question.

Comment: @StephenD are you including the precompiled header with the instantiation in your `IT_TimeOnly` header?

Comment: Yes. I have 'template TimeOnly IT_TimeOnly::operator++<TimeOnly>(int);' in my pre-compiled header.

Comment: @vsoftco: there is nothing wrong with your answer: the explicit instantiation doesn't change the fact that the compiler can't deduce which operator to call without the explicit template argument being specified.

Comment: In that case I would expect to see an ambiguity error, not a missing operator error. Since it is being called on the base class, it should use the templated baseclass operator.

Comment: @DietmarKühl I wasn't sure, thanks. So you're saying that first the compiler tries do deduce the type, and only after the type is deduced it considers the possible instantiations in the set of candidates, is this true?

Comment: @vsoftco: yes. The explicit instantiation doesn't change that overload resolution happens first. All it may change are the names visible at the point of instantiation.

Comment: @DietmarKühl Am I missing something? I can't see an answer from vsoftco, only two questions. If you think that you have the answer, can you explain it a little more clearly?

Comment: @StephenD: the answer from vsoftco is deleted. However, with enough reputation it can still be seen. The answer is pretty much what my answer says with respect to the reason (the template argument can't be deduced) but missing the alternative (use a non-member `operator++()`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler can't deduce the template argument `T` from the call. As a result the explicit instantiation fails. The existance of an explicit instantiation is irrelevant as first the overload is determined, then an instantion is looked for or created. However, the function look-up already fails.

It seems you are trying to define you increment operator in the base class to return an object of the derived class. That's not going to work for a member function unless you parameterize the base with the derived type (CRTP). Assuming you constrain the template appropriately it should be possible to implement the operator as a non-member delegating to a suitable member function to do the appropriate increment.

Comment: Kuhl Thank you for your answer. I know this is not the way to get polymorphism, and I know about the CRTP solution. I am not trying to use this code for real, I am simply experimenting with templates and wanted to understand why this didn't work. I understand that the compiler can't deduce the template argument, because it is in the return type. But when explicitly instantiated does it not become a member of the base class, as if it were not templated?

Comment: @StephenD: no, a template stays a template even if it is explicitly instantiated. The primary uses of explicit instantiations is to avoid having the template code in the header and, in compination with extern template instantiations, to avoid instantiating template code in every translation unit for often used template instantiations (to inprove compile times).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @DietmarKühl and @vsoftco for your helpful answers. To summarise your answers:...

All calls to templated functions where the template parameter is not an argument type must be qualified with the template parameter, even if the version you want to use has been explicitly instantiated. In principle there could be multiple instantiations of different types, and the compiler must know which to choose.